# Create a list with items from a nested dict key value pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

I would like to create a new list with items from a large nested dict.

Here is a snippet of the nested dict:

**AcceptedAnswersPython_combined.json**

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "answers": [
        {
          "creation_date": 1533083368,
          "is_accepted": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1533083567,
          "is_accepted": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1533083754,
          "is_accepted": true
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1533084669,
          "is_accepted": false
        },
        {
          "creation_date": 1533089107,
          "is_accepted": false
        }
      ],
      "creation_date": 1533083248,
      "tags": [
        "python",
        "pandas",
        "dataframe"
      ]
    },
    {
      "answers": [
        {
          "creation_date": 1533084137,
          "is_accepted": true
        }
      ],
      "creation_date": 1533083367,
      "tags": [
        "python",
        "binary-search-tree"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The new list should contain the `creation_date` of each item as many times as there are dicts inside the `answers` list.
So in case of the code snippet above the new list should look like this:

```
question_date_per_answer = [[1533083248, 1533083248, 1533083248 , 1533083248, 1533083248], [1533083367]]
```

The reason why I need this new list is that I would like to determine the difference between each `answers` `creation_date` and its associated question `creation_date`(stated inside the each `items` dict).

This new list should look like this in pandas Dataframe:

```
     question creation date answer creation date  
0          1533083248             1533083368               
1          1533083248             1533083567               
2          1533083248             1533083754                
3          1533083248             1533084669               
4          1533083248             1533089107               
5          1533083367             1533084137
```

I can iterate through all question like so:

```
items = json.load(open('AcceptedAnswersPython_combined.json'))['items']
question_creation_date = [item['creation_date'] for item in items]
```

But this leaves me with a list which is unequal to the number of `answers` `creation_date`.

I can't get my head around this.
So how do I create such a list where the amount of question creation dates is equal to the amount of answer creation dates? (like `question_date_per_answer`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Multiply the `item['creation_date']` as a list as many times as you have answers (i.e. `[item['creation_date']] * len(item['answers'])`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to iterate over item["answers"] and then get creation_date for each answer in oreder to get answer creation dates.

```
my_json = """{
"items": [
    {
    "answers": [
        {
        "creation_date": 1533083368,
        "is_accepted": false
        },
        {
        "creation_date": 1533083567,
        "is_accepted": false
        },
        {
        "creation_date": 1533083754,
        "is_accepted": true
        },
        {
        "creation_date": 1533084669,
        "is_accepted": false
        },
        {
        "creation_date": 1533089107,
        "is_accepted": false
        }
    ],
    "creation_date": 1533083248,
    "tags": [
        "python",
        "pandas",
        "dataframe"
    ]
    },
    {
    "answers": [
        {
        "creation_date": 1533084137,
        "is_accepted": true
        }
    ],
    "creation_date": 1533083367,
    "tags": [
        "python",
        "binary-search-tree"
    ]
    }
]
}"""

import json

data = json.loads(my_json)
dates = [(question["creation_date"], answer["creation_date"])
         for question in data["items"] for answer in question["answers"]]
print(dates)
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick :). I modified dates a bit, but it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can still work with the list at hand.
Lets try making a dataframe from the list that you already have-

```
l = [[1533083248, 1533083248, 1533083248 , 1533083248, 1533083248], [1533083367]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Unfortunately you get the following-

```
0   1   2   3   4
0   1533083248  1.533083e+09    1.533083e+09    1.533083e+09    1.533083e+09
1   1533083367  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

So we need to transpose it. For that lets do the following -

```
from itertools import zip_longest
k = list(list(zip_longest(*l))) #Unless the list will be truncated to the length of shortest list.
df = pd.DataFrame(k)
```

Output-

```
0   1
0   1533083248  1.533083e+09
1   1533083248  NaN
2   1533083248  NaN
3   1533083248  NaN
4   1533083248  NaN
```

Now we will forward fill the NaNs with the previous value by -
`df.fillna(method='ffill')`
Whole snippet -

```
from itertools import zip_longest
l=[1533083248, 1533083248, 1533083248 , 1533083248, 1533083248], [1533083367]
k=list(list(zip_longest(*l)))
df = pd.DataFrame(k)
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Voila -

```
    0   1
0   1533083248  1.533083e+09
1   1533083248  1.533083e+09
2   1533083248  1.533083e+09
3   1533083248  1.533083e+09
4   1533083248  1.533083e+09
```